# Reading in sets of 64 characters from a file

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, filereader

So I'm trying to read in a string from a file. However, I want each string to contain exactly 64 characters or less if the last string doesn't have 64 in it. So essentially I have a counter, when that counter reaches 64, I set the array of characters to a string, go to the next row and reset the count to zero. However I'm not getting output of any kind when I run it. Any help is appreciated. Here is a snippet of my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    File input = null;
    if (1 < args.length) {
        input = new File(args[1]);
    }     
    else {
        System.err.println("Invalid arguments count:" + args.length);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    String key = args[0];
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    int len;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many lines in the file?");
    if(scan.hasNextInt()){
        len = scan.nextInt();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
        scan.next();
        len = scan.nextInt();
    }
    scan.close();
    String[] inputText = new String[2 * len];
    String[] encryptText = new String[2 * len];
    char[][] inputCharArr = new char[2 * len][64];
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
    int r;
    int counter = 0;
    int row = 0;
    while ((r = reader.read()) != -1) {
        char ch = (char) r;
        if(counter == 64){
            String temp = new String(inputCharArr[row]);
            inputText[row] = temp;
            encryptText[row] = inputText[row];
            System.out.println(inputText[row]);
            row++;
            counter = 0;
        }
        if(row == len){
            break;
        }
        inputCharArr[row][counter] = ch;
        counter++;
    }
```

---

Edit: Is this close?

```
        CharBuffer cbuf = CharBuffer.allocate(64);
    int counter = 0;
    while (reader.read(cbuf) != -1) {
        inputText[counter] = cbuf.toString();
        encryptText[counter] = inputText[counter];
        counter++;
        cbuf.clear();
    }
```

Comment: To read 64 characters from a file, create a `char[64]` buffer and call [`read(char[] cbuf)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html). *Much* faster (and easier) than calling `read()` 64 times.

Comment: Could you maybe provide me a little example of how I would use that?

Comment: Ah okay I got it now, create a char array of size 64 and read into that. thanks for the help man!